# C# stripping out the string needed

Tags: c#

Ok so i have these strings

```
 location = "C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\399";
 location = "C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\399\\DISK1";
 location = "C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\399\\DISK2";
 location = "\\somewhere\\on\\Network\\399\\DISK2";
```

how do i strip out the 399 from all these situations ....FYI the number might be 2 digits like 42 so i cant grab the last 3 in the first case....i was thinking of some regex that would take out the DISKn if it exists and grab the number till the \ before the number but i dont know how to do that in C#...any ideas

Comment: I assume it won't always be 399 you're looking for?

Comment: A Regular Expression is what you need. http://txt2re.com/index.php3?s=27%3AFeb%3A2012+%22This+is+an+Example%21%22&submit=Show+Matches

Comment: correct it wont be always 399... and as for what i tried...substring but i cant get the right combination

Comment: @Matt, you need to provide more info, because this is way too general. WHAT are you trying to achieve? How do you know which part of the string you want (from a human perspective)?

Comment: @walther - sorry i must of not been clear....what i want to get that number so i can create a report with that number for reference...so i want to  get the 399 and create a file called my_report_for_399

Comment: Is it possible to have a path like "\\somewhere\\on\\Network\\112233\\399\\DISK2";? I.e. multiple folders of all numerics?

Comment: @Matt, once again - how do you know (as a human being), that you want THAT number from the path and not the other? Would it be the last occurrence of some number characters? Would it be under some specific directory? Etc.

Comment: Another way of asking - is it always the case that the folder you want is ALWAYS the *last* folder in the path that is made up entirely of NUMERICS and nothing else? i.e. can we presume that this is not possible: "C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\399\\DISK2\\112233";?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do this with Regex against your example input:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("\\\d+");
string result = rgx.Replace(input, string.Empty);
```

The regular expression will match on a `\` followed by at least one digit and replace them. You need to be careful though, as it will not preserve the string if you have this pattern elsewhere in the string.

If your inputs are exactly as you have described, using `string.Split` can be much more efficient (assuming the portion you need to remove is always last of before last).

---

Update:

The regex I provided will work only if you have a *single* part of the path that starts with numbers, not multiples or paths that have *begin* with numbers but do not end with them.

The information you have provided is not enough to built a regular expression that will do as you wish - how do you distinguish between numeric paths that do need to be stripped out and those that do not, for example?

Comment: What if another folder name is made up of digits? e.g. "\\somewhere\\on\\Network\\112233\\399\\DISK2"; Might have to ask the OP if this a possible scenario?

Comment: @Magrangs - one can only answer what was given. The OP has not provided such inputs.

Comment: @Oded, but that is quite irrelevant. You're really trying to help or to get some points only? He said he wants to extract some part from the path. Does he really need to be explicit for you to see many possible path combinations and situations?

Comment: Its seems that the scenario described above is possible (see comments on the question itself - I asked the OP). In this situation, your regex would not work, which is a shame as it now makes the regex more complicated :-(

Comment: @walther - Irrelevant? One needs to tailor the Regex to the input. I only know what the OP has posted and have put in my answer a warning regarding what is not covered (i.e. having the pattern repeated in the input would string it everywhere).

Answer (score 2):

```
var parts = location.Split('\\');
var number = parts.Last().Starts("DISK") ? parts[parts.Length - 2] : parts[parts.Length - 1];
```

strip number out:

```
var index = parts.Last().Starts("DISK") ? parts.Length - 2 : parts.Length - 1;
var newParts = parts.Take(index).Concat(parts.Skip(index + 1)).ToArray();
var newLocation = string.Join("\\", newParts);
```

Comment: This _returns_ the number, it does not strip it out, as the OP requires.

Comment: What if the path changes? I assume that part "somewhere\on\network" can be basically any path. You can't generalize it like this without thinking of possible problems...

Comment: @walther it's generalized as soon as posible

Comment: @DarkGray, from your perspective? Maybe. From OP's perspective? I don't think so. Have you read his comments? Are you really sure that you have a grasp of his intentions?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Split() method for breaking the string up around separators. Then you can use techniques such as checking for the last part starting with DISK, or checking for a part that is purely integer (possibly risky, in case higher subdirectories are pure numbers - unless you work from the back!).

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = int.Parse(location.Split(new string[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[4]);
```

Comment: What if the path gets longer?